# Using variables in postman

Tags: postman

there is a link that generates basic information for registrations, as shown in the link and image below:

https://www.4devs.com.br/ferramentas_online.php

[image: loading the variables]

This information is used to fill in data for a post call from a service, but it stopped working and I don't know why.

[image: using the variables]

Do you know what it could be?

Comment: What stopped working? You haven't really explained that. Is there an environment selected that these values are getting set into?

Answer (score 0):

Because your response is an array, not an object, therefore in order to getting value, you need a specific index.
`jsonData.nome` --> `jsonData[0].nome`

For example

```
pm.environment.set("nome", jsonData[0].nome);
```

Comment: and how can I go through the results, since I managed to get the first value, but the others give an error?

Comment: @AndersonSilva I don't understand what you want. Please update question or create new one with adequate information.